# (Magento 2) Modify Select.php in Vendor Module-Catalog

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to override the "Select.php" file at: /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/ but I'm not sure where to put the modified "Select.php" file. The only thing I changed was commenting out the "--Please Select--" line 47.

Where do I put the modified "Select.php" file?

I am using stock Magento theme.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a small module to override this file.

1. Create a module under

   > app/code//Catalog/
2. Create `module.xml` under `app/code/<vendor_name>/Catalog/etc`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="<vendor_name>_Catalog" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create `registraion.php` on module root folder, that is `app/code/<vendor_name>/Catalog/`:

   ```
   <?php

   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       '<vendor_name>_Catalog',
       __DIR__
   );
   ?>
   ```
4. Create `di.xml` under `app/code/<vendor_name>/Catalog/etc`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="<vendor_name>\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
   </config>
   ```
5. Finally, create `Select.php` under `app/code/<vendor_name>/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type`. The file should be look like this:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace <vendor_name>\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

   class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
   {
       public function getValuesHtml()
       {
           //do your stuff

       }
   }
   ```

You should able to override the getValuesHtml functions on template file.